# How to pick specific subjects in R

Tags: r

tried to pick up 2 random subjects, but don't know how to do in R

```
random.subj <- sample(1:max(Data$Id), 2)
rd <- subset(Data$Id, Data$Id==random.subj)
```

I have a dataset "Data" like

```
Id 
1
1
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
...
```

Comment: Have you read the help documentation for `subset`? It's kind of rude to ask such a basic question here when you haven't bothered to learn how it works yourself

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case `random.subj` will be a vector of two elements. In that case, doing an equality comparison with `==` probably isn't want you want because it will just recycle through the shorter list to perform the comparison rather than checking each row for either value as you probably intend.

Also i'm not sure if all your IDs are numerical and sequential. It's better to just take a random sample from the IDs themselves rather than from the index of the IDs.

Fixing the second problem first

```
random.subj <- sample(Data$Id, 2)
```

Actually, if you just want two IDs then that's all you need, but if you want the data for those IDs then

```
rd <- subset(Data, Data$Id %in% random.subj)
```

is the correct way to extract it.

Comment: Thank you MrFlick!! This is exotically what I wanted!! But I need more reputations to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: You might want that to be `sample(unique(Data$Id, 2))` if you don't want the chance to pick the same ID twice.